# Centos7: docker swarm services cannot communicate over Overlay network

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, overlay, centos7, docker-swarm

I have a swarm with 3 CentOS7 nodes running on openstack.
I created an overlay network with

```
docker network create --driver overlay p3net_test
```

Then I create 2 services named "nexus" and "nginx_nexus"

```
docker service create --name nexus --network p3net_test sonatype/docker-nexus3
docker service create -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name nginx_nexus --network p3net_test nginx-img
```

I find that the inter container communication does not work. I am trying to use nginx as reverse proxy for nexus repo and I have tested it without swarm. Here is my [nginx.conf](https://github.com/akailash/nginx_nexus/blob/master/nginx.conf) file where I set upstream to nexus. The VIP does not get resolved. My containers cannot talk to each other.

Current update:I saw that CentOS7 uses 3.10 kernel and there are some issues with kernel version lower than 3.16 and overlay networks. Will try updating the kernel.

Comment: Kernel Version: 4.4.63-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 updated. Still not solved.

Comment: problem is solved using ubuntu16.04 instead of centos7.